# Reshape BroadcastReceiver to JobScheduler

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, job-scheduling, android-broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

I'm working on a smal WebView app for android. To check the internet connectivity the app use a Broadcastreceiver on app-level. The problem is, that the BroadcastReceiver is still active even if the app is closed and crashes with a NullPointerException. I catched it on a quick way, but it's not a propper way to do it.

To solve further problems and increase the coding level I want to reshape my BroadcastReceiver from the app-level to the activity-level with a JobScheduler. But it's quite difficult. I can't the point or a description where to start. Has anybody done this before and can help me?

The code of my Broadcastreceiver:

Androidmanifest.xml

```
        <application
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".helper.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

NetworkChangeReceiver.java

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public interface NetworkChangeCallback {
    void networkChange(int conn);
}

public static NetworkChangeCallback networkChangeCallback;

public static void setInterface(Context context) {
    networkChangeCallback = (NetworkChangeCallback)context;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    Log.i("WIFISTATE ACTION",intent.getAction());
    Log.i("WIFISTATE STATUS",status);
    if(networkChangeCallback!=null) {
        networkChangeCallback.networkChange(conn);
    }
}
}
```

I'm thankful for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to call receiver explicitly because implicitly receiver not works on oreo and above O.S. On `OnStart()` method you have to call explicitly like following and then on `onStop()` or `onPause()` have to unRegister the receiver

To register:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver ();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

To unregister:

```
   try {

        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        BalanceReceiver=null;

        registeredReceivers.clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Hope, It'll help you.

Comment: Are you using a JobScheduler? I don't know what the propper way for a NetworkChangereceiver is. Developer.Android suggest using a JobScheduler to handle this. But I have no idea how to reshape my working NetworkChangeReceiver f.e. into a NetworkChangeJobScheduler.

Comment: No, I am not using JobScheduler. But BroadcastReceiver which explicitly gets called. I have tested on Oreo O.S as well and works fine.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry, but as I said, I want to work with the Broadcastreceiver on app level, not on activity level. Using your code means I have to register the BroadcastReceiver for every Activity.

Comment: It'll work for the whole app, not for a particular activity. :)

Comment: Let me know the whole scenario, then I'd be able to help you buddy.